# linear algebra - orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Determine an orthonormal basis {e1, e2, e3} such that e1 is parallel to the vector u = (1, 2, -1).

Can you please help me find the ON-basis ?

Comment: Do you know about the Gram-Schmidt algorithm?

Comment: no i dont know, is there any other method i can use?

Comment: If you can come up with a vector $v$ orthogonal to $u$, you can normalise $u$, $v$ and $u\times v$ (cross product) and use as your basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know Gram-Schmidt, then you can go directly. Find the vectors that are orthogonal to $(1,2,-1)$: this means
$$
(x,y,z)\cdot(1,2,-1)=0
$$
or
$$
x+2y-z=0
$$
Set $z=0$, for instance, and $y=1$, so you find $(-2,1,0)$.

Now you have two orthogonal vectors and you need a third one. Add the equation $(x,y,z)\cdot(-2,1,0)=0$ getting
$$
\begin{cases}
x+2y-z=0\\
-2x+y=0
\end{cases}
$$
Take $y=1$ that gives $x=2$ and $z=4$. Thus we have the three vectors
$$
(1,2,-1),\quad (-2,1,0),\quad (2,1,4)
$$
These form an orthogonal basis (why?). For an orthonormal one, just multiply each one of those vectors by the inverse of its norm:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(1,2,-1),\quad 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(-2,1,0),\quad
\frac{1}{\sqrt{21}}(2,1,4)
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can start by picking any basis, and then applying the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to get an orthonormal one.

For example, pick ${(1,2,-1),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)}$ as your Basis.

Project $(0,1,0)$ onto $(1,2,-1)$ then substract the result from $(0,1,0)$. Wikipedia gives this as follows: $\text{proj}_u = \frac{<u,v>}{<u,u>}v$.

$\text{proj}_{(1,2,-1)}(0,1,0) = \frac{<(1,2,-1), (0,1,0)>}{<(1,2,-1), (1,2,-1)>}(1,2,-1) = \frac{2}{6}(1,2,-1) = (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{-1}{3})$.

This gives a new second vector which is orthogonal to the first one, namely:
$(0,1,0) - (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{-1}{3}) = (\frac{-1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{-1}{3})$. Orthogonality is verified by $<(1,2,-1),(\frac{-1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{-1}{3})> = \frac{-1+2-1}{3} = 0$.

But I'll have to side with Mnifldz here, the article on Wikipedia and this small example calculation should be enough to figure it out. (i.e. next you project $(0,0,1)$ onto each of the first vectors and substract the result.)

Comment: Full solution plz :)

Comment: One moment plz :)

Comment: @user2393690 You should explain what specifically you're having trouble with and demonstrate you've put time, effort, and research into the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: If i know how to solve it, i will not ask here :(

Comment: @RolfSievers thank you